# how to configure the download button on LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

`<a href="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}">Download</a>`

When I do that the image opens on a page or I want to be able to download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `download` attribute to your anchor

```html
<a href="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}" download>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `download` attribute.

```
<a download="nameOfImage"  href="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}">Download</a>
```